# Does fishing in a different direction cause problems?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using an AFK fish farm and noticed that about over half the loot I get from fishing gets stuck behind a hopper (I'm using Panda's design, modified by Kabood). In my first farm, I fished East, and at least most of the loot I collected was collected by hoppers (I'm pretty sure all of it was collected, but I never did check to see if anything got stuck since it ran so smoothly). I had to move the farm, and now I fish South.

As earlier mentioned, about half the loot I collect never makes it to the hoppers; it gets stuck behind one of them. Since the old design worked pretty much perfectly, does fishing in a different direction affect how well I can fish? I'm on 1.11.2.

I am also 90% sure the design I currently have is the same to the old one. I did add some blocks on the side and lighting above the farm for decorative purposes.

The farm:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Where items get stuck:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some images of your farm, as well as the original design? Also, what version of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: Added the pics and version, but I don't have any pics of the original design.

Comment: Is that a fence post below the water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since AFK Fishing farms exploit glitched mechanics (i.e. the constant "non-casting" against certain objects), it's difficult to pin down exactly whether or not your facing (north, south, etc.) has anything to do with it, without extensive testing. From my experience however, I don't believe it is the case.

As for *why* the items are getting caught, I might suggest the place where you are standing could possibly have something to do with it. All of the AFK Fishing Farm designs I have seen, suggest standing with the water at head height. So try standing one block lower, and see if that has any effect.

My other suggestion is to replace the fencepost beneath the water. Fence posts are odd blocks; they have thinner, and taller hitboxes than normal blocks - it's 1.5 blocks tall, and .5 blocks wide, effectively creating an area wehere items can hit it and get knocked "off-course", as you can see from my very basic depiction here. The hit box for a normal block, vs a fence post.

[image: Block and fence post hitbox]

I would suggest that unless it is absolutely essential, replace it with a normal block.

Comment: I replaced the cobblestone wall with an upside down half slab and so far everything is working perfectly :) I'll accept your answer if things continue to work as smoothly as they have been.